# Bug with stain lines when using ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Create some view and put it in `ScrollView`.

**Important:** The view should be less than iPhone screen bounds to observe the bug. If we make `ScrollView` full-screen (from left to right bounds) the bug isn't observed.

The bug is observed on any simulator model.

*Platform*: iOS 15.4
*Xcode*: Version 13.3 (13E113)
*Machine*: MacBook Air M1 2020

Pictures (watch the white lines on the right and on the bottom):

[image][image]

**Sample code:**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var text: String {
        """
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ultrices nec erat ut dictum. Mauris non urna ac leo eleifend commodo ac eu neque. Aenean tellus orci, dictum vel ullamcorper eu, condimentum vitae arcu. Vivamus consectetur sem tellus, in efficitur ante fringilla non. Nam eleifend dui vel felis mattis, eu mattis nunc fermentum. Curabitur feugiat arcu convallis, sodales felis vel, condimentum ipsum. Curabitur auctor urna mauris, sit amet porttitor justo cursus at. Mauris condimentum mi ac velit sollicitudin, ac commodo tortor imperdiet. Vestibulum consectetur, purus quis vulputate condimentum, libero libero imperdiet massa, in imperdiet enim dolor at erat. Nulla sapien dui, maximus id rhoncus eu, luctus at tellus. Praesent rutrum velit vel libero sodales eleifend. Phasellus in condimentum lectus.

        Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent et sapien sapien. Sed dapibus mi vitae porttitor vulputate. Suspendisse vel erat blandit, pellentesque leo vitae, mattis leo. Pellentesque dictum ex sit amet nibh molestie, in hendrerit nibh accumsan. Sed mollis neque quam, rhoncus elementum ex efficitur eget. Nunc quis tristique leo. Nullam sed rhoncus massa, quis blandit nisi. In pharetra pretium eros, non convallis felis mattis in. Sed eleifend elit risus, in tincidunt massa varius id. Morbi velit nunc, faucibus eget est eu, porttitor pharetra mauris. Nam aliquam ligula diam, nec commodo elit commodo ut. Nunc consectetur fermentum est, placerat eleifend neque dictum id.

        Nullam et lobortis metus. In eget metus lacinia, bibendum augue eget, elementum nibh. Quisque tempor lorem nec purus dapibus finibus. Vivamus dui enim, viverra et mattis quis, dictum sit amet erat. Mauris nec purus hendrerit, elementum nibh id, mollis urna. Nulla molestie mi id turpis egestas tincidunt. Praesent porttitor, lorem nec venenatis gravida, libero est vulputate mauris, eu elementum sem augue eget magna. Pellentesque vehicula mauris non nibh volutpat vestibulum. Vestibulum auctor dictum sapien a fringilla. Quisque sed mauris ex. Maecenas at tortor sit amet ligula pretium vehicula. Pellentesque tempor lectus sed dui sollicitudin, ut luctus diam tincidunt. Morbi a vestibulum ante. Donec elementum sed lorem nec ornare. Nam varius dignissim ante. Nullam aliquam vitae magna sit amet viverra.
        """
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Background {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                TextSheet {
                    Text(text)
                        .padding(24)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextSheet<Content: View>: View {
    private let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            content()
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 32)
    }
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}

struct Background<Content: View>: View {
    private let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            content()
                .clipped()
        }
    }
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is a simplified example to show the bug, I know there're better ways to implement text views.

If we enable scroll indicators the problem goes away:

```swift
...Background {
       ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
           TextSheet {...
```

However, in our case, the problem resolves only in the vertical direction since this is the only direction which is being involved. Removing `.vertical` doesn't help either:

```swift
...Background {
       ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
           TextSheet {...
```

I suppose that this is a SwiftUI 3 bug, but I haven't found a workaround for this or the respective Apple Developer Forum discussion of the bug.

Comment: Not seeing the lines. Xcode 13.3, iOS 15.4 simulator and device. It sounds like some issue with your simulator. Also, why not make `TextSheet` and  `Background` view modifiers? The implementation is a bit more straightforward.

Comment: I consider that modifiers change the properties of the view. But `TextSheet` and `Background` are not properties but independent view elements. Anyway, it doesn't change the subject of the question.
And what about the reproducibility: thank you for the try! Maybe it's indeed something wrong with my simulator.